# How to loop a text whilst pressing enter (Python)

Tags: python

Is there a way in which I can allow this ">" to come up when the user presses enter or return, instead of doing this:

```
cout = input(">")
sip = input(">")
vat = input(">")
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to change the standard prompt of `>>> ` to just `>`?

Comment: If I understand you right, you can use a loop. Like this `while True: var = input(">")` Everytime user hits enter, new prompt will be shown.

Comment: Thanks Isamert, worked!

Comment: @MLCLOUD are you trying to actually save the results of the `input` ?

Comment: Yes, in a variable

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make a loop that will print ">" on enter try something like this

```
while True:    # infinite loop
    userInput = input("Enter Text: ")
    if userInput == "":
        print ("> ")  # prints ">"
```

Comment: How is this different from the sample code in the question?

Comment: I know this, I am using Python 3x, so raw_imput dosent work. What i want is a loop so that the program prints ">" whenever they hit enter or return.

Comment: Oh I see sorry my mistake so you just want to make a loop on enter or return to print ">"?

Comment: Yes, so it prints it endlessly.

Comment: Ok I have changed my answer sorry for the misconfusion

Comment: Sorry mate, i knew this too. The answer was already solved by Isamert in the comments. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Ok, well I updated the answer to more reflect what you were trying to get at

Comment: zircon-lang.weebly.com